# How to use BoxCutter to take screenshot by using command line options in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, multiple-monitors

I was looking for a way to take screenshot by using command line options of buxcutter.exe but i have no knowledge what are the arguments to pass for taking a screenshot. And i mostly want to take screenshots from different monitors.

I am using following codes to start process:

```
var cmdScreenCaputeLocation:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("assets\\boxcutter.exe");
var nativeProcessStartInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
nativeProcessStartInfo.executable = cmdScreenCaputeLocation;
var nativeProcess:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
nativeProcess.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT,screenCaptureNativeProcessComplated);
nativeProcess.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA,screenCapturOonErrorS);
nativeProcess.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_INPUT_IO_ERROR,screenCaptureOnError);
nativeProcess.start(nativeProcessStartInfo);
```

If anybody know what are the arguments i have to pass so that i can take screenshots from different monitors, please help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Usage : boxcutter [OPTIONS] [OUTPUT_FILENAME]

OPTIONS  
-c, = coords X1,Y1,X2,Y2 capture the rectangle (X1,Y1)-(X2,Y2).  
-f, = to capture the full screen screenshot.  
-v, = to display version information.  
-h, = to display help message.  

For Full Screen : boxcutter -f testgrab.png
By Coordinate : boxcutter -c X1,Y1,X2,Y2 testgrab.png
```

(Where X1 = Starting X Coordinate,X2 = Ending X Coordinate,Y1 = Starting Y Coordinate,Y2 = Ending Y Coordinate)

Answer (score 1):

Directly from the boxcutter main page http://keepnote.org/boxcutter/:

```
usage: boxcutter [OPTIONS] [OUTPUT_FILENAME]

Saves a screenshot to 'OUTPUT_FILENAME' if given.  Only output formats
"*.bmp" and "*.png" are supported.  If no file name is given,
screenshot is stored on clipboard by default.

OPTIONS
  -c, --coords X1,Y1,X2,Y2    capture the rectange (X1,Y1)-(X2,Y2)
  -f, --fullscreen            fullscreen screenshot
  -v, --version               display version information
  -h, --help                  display help message
```